# How to add files to Xcode project programmatically / from a script?

Tags: xcode, build

Right now I'm downloading all resources and adding the references via Xcode GUI. 
There must be a way to automate this last step, so that a script can copying the resources to the project-directory automatically and generate the references.

In some similar questions it means to build a "new 'run script' build phase to your project." 
But how is the code, that adds it in a subdirectory of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish this question:
I found a solution like this:

```
find -L "${SRCROOT}/Resources/InitData" -type f -not -name “.*” -not -name “`basename ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`” | xargs -t -I {} cp {} ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/;
find -L "${SRCROOT}/Resources/InitData/Images" -type f -not -name “.*” -not -name “`basename ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`” | xargs -t -I {} cp {} ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/;
```

Added this in the build section as an initial run script worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tool that exists currently. I also had the need for adding files and folders programmatically to an xcode project file. It was rather involved, so I will describe the method and post a link to my project.

If you add just one file or one folder to the project file and look at the diff, you will discover that each file/folder has multiple entries in the project file that share a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). You have to generate a UUID and create entries in the respective subsections of the project file.

[My use case](https://github.com/anconaesselmann/ObjcVsSwift) was to measure if there are any differences in compilation time between projects that use swift and/or objective c files. [This section of code](https://github.com/anconaesselmann/ObjcVsSwift/blob/master/generateProjectFiles.swift#L458) manipulates the project file. It is quickly thrown together and won't win any awards for beauty.